# Convert DateTime to PRTime C#

Tags: c#, firefox

I am working in Firefox's *places.sqlite* file and need to convert the local DateTime to [PRTime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netscape_Portable_Runtime#Time), using C#. PRTime is "a 64-bit integer representing the number of microseconds since midnight (00:00:00) 1 January 1970 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)) to a datetime."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with this little helper class here:

```
    public static class TimeHelper
    {
        // PRTime is Int64 count of microseconds from 1970-01-01-00-00-0000
        static Int64 ToPRTime(DateTime dateTime)
        {
            TimeSpan t = (dateTime - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1));
            return Convert.ToInt64(t.TotalMilliseconds * 1000);
        }

        static DateTime FromPrTime(Int64 prTime)
        {
            var someDate = new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            var milliSeconds = prTime / 1000;
           return someDate.AddMilliseconds(milliSeconds);
        }
    }
```

Comment: in the example I use UTC time. you are in UTC +6 I believe. Try DateTime.Now, this should be what you expect